# MySQL query executes but does not update column

Tags: mysql, database

I need to adjust my query . My query is:

```
update tests
  set test_typeid = '10' 
where 
  test_siteid IN (
    select t.test_siteid 
    from companies c 
    left join sites s on 
      c.company_id = s.site_companyid 
    left join tests t on
      t.test_siteid = s.site_id 
    where 
      c.company_id = '35' and 
      t.test_typeid = '20' and
      s.site_id = '1149' 
    limit 100
  )
```

Here I need to update value **'10'** for test_typeid column of **'tests'** table. In subquery (i meant "select query") , I just retrieved the columns which are under my conditions. In my table it returns one single row. The test_siteid is **'1149'** as i expect. It is correct. but the update is not worked. I tried with above query and it sows success message. But it does not worked. Kindly help. If any queries please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for errors when you execute the query.  That query should cause a syntax error in MySQL.

Comment: No there is no errors. it shows success message.

Comment: Why are there php/jquery tags? There is no code to support the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- fixed it :)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I just need to adjust my query. I dont need any scripting language help.

Comment: @KarthikRajan Your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44824167/1 and a few revisions after that had both `jquery` and `php` tags used. That was why I asked. If there is relevance, you should include the code for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh. Okay I understood. Anyway I need a help to build a single query to update from my conditions.

Comment: Also I tried with below:

`update tests t left outer join sites s on t.test_siteid = s.site_id left outer join companies c set t.test_typeid = '10' where c.company_id = '35' and t.test_typeid = '20' and s.site_id = '1149'`